# retrieving multiple association data with conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I've been a programmer for a few years (I've mainly used PHP / CakePHP) but I'm new to Ruby on Rails.

I have a question regarding retrieving data for multiple associations with conditions.

I have the following four models:

```
class Questionnaire < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sections
end

class Section < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :questionnaire
  has_many :questions
  has_many :non_questions

  def elements
    (questions + non_questions).sort_by(&:order)
  end

end

class Question < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :section

  validates_date :starts_on, allow_blank: true
  validates_date :expires_on, allow_blank: true
end

class NonQuestion < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :section
end
```

I currently want to show the whole questionnaire in the view - that is all the sections with their questions and non_questions in one page and in the right order. I would also like to pass a date parameter from the view, which will be used to retrieve the corresponding active questions only, based on the starts_on and expires_on date columns.

Using CakePHP, I would preload and store all the data in a variable in my model by using Left Joins with conditions. I tried to do something similar with rails (using all possible combinations of joins, includes, left_outer_joins) with a where condition, but when I, for example, call `questionnaire.sections.first.elements` it runs a new query without applying my condition. Am I missing something out? Is there a "right", ruby way to do something like this? Or given what my application requires, is there a better way to approach this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For eager loader in rails, you use `includes`. For your models, for example, you could do something like:

```
Questionnaire.includes(sections: [:questions, :non_questions]).references(:question).where("(questions.exp‌​ires_on >= :time OR questions.expires_on IS NULL) AND (questions.starts_on IS NULL OR questionsstarts_on <= :time)" , time: Time.now)
```

If you want to access that set of records you retrieved multiple times, you should assign then to some variable, so it doesn't make a new query on db. Hope it enlightened your question

Comment: this worked but I found out that it needed a .references(:question) because the condition had to do with the question model. If you amend your answer I will mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: @Thanos Ei, bro... guess you forgot to mark the answer. Could you do that please? thanks!

Comment: yes sure but could you add the missing .references first please? The full answer is Questionnaire.includes(section: [:questions, :non_questions]).references(:question).where(your_conditions)

Comment: @Thanos oh, sure! I didn't noticed the conditions part... thanks!

Comment: Hi Ronan, it's not the conditions that it was the problem. Because the conditions concern a child model, we need to add .references(*table_names) as per http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/references. So the full answer is: Questionnaire.includes(sections: [:questions, :non_questions]).references(:question).where("(questions.expires_on >= :time OR questions.expires_on IS NULL) AND (questions.starts_on IS NULL OR questionsstarts_on <= :time)" , time: Time.now)

Comment: @Thanos oh, I never used that "references" before. It's nice that I learned it too. Fixed it, thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
Questionnaire.includes(
  sections: [:questions, :non_questions]
).where("questions.starts_on <= :time AND questions.expires_on > :time", time: Time.now)
```